# Http server, when do I send the data?

Tags: android, http, http-headers

I have built a file server in Java and I'm having difficulties with understanding when I should start serving the file data.  As you can see below are two different client requests.  Some provide two request and I'm not sure when I should start serving the data and when I should "ignore".

**Client #1:**

```
06-15 08:06:21.290: VERBOSE/HttpSession(9425): SESSION 1: STARTED
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): CLIENT: 
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): GET /stream HTTP/1.1
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Host: 127.0.0.1:37914
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): User-Agent: (Linux)
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): SERVER:
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 12:06:21 GMT
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Server: HTTP Server
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Aug 2009 01:02:23 GMT
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Accept-Ranges: none
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Content-Type: audio/mpeg 
06-15 08:06:21.290: INFO/HttpSession(9425): 
06-15 08:06:26.720: VERBOSE/HttpSession(9425): SESSION 2: STARTED
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): CLIENT: 
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): GET /stream HTTP/1.1
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Host: 127.0.0.1:37914
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Accept: */*
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): SERVER:
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 12:06:26 GMT
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Server: HTTP Server
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Aug 2009 01:02:23 GMT
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Accept-Ranges: none
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): Content-Type: audio/mpeg 
06-15 08:06:26.730: INFO/HttpSession(9425): 
06-15 08:06:26.730: VERBOSE/HttpSession(9425): SESSION 2: ENDED
```

**Client #2:**

```
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): CLIENT: 
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): GET /stream HTTP/1.1
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): Host: 127.0.0.1
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): Accept: */*
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): Icy-MetaData:1
06-15 05:03:58.079 I/HttpSession(18335): User-Agent: QuickTime;NvMM HTTP Client v0.1
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): SERVER:
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): Date: Wed, 15 Jun 2011 09:03:58 GMT
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): Server: HTTP Server
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Aug 2009 01:02:23 GMT
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): Accept-Ranges: bytes
06-15 05:03:58.089 I/HttpSession(18335): Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

Comment: You shold also log the Headers on the Clients side (curl -v). The Clients behaviour seems a bit odd, because typically a Client sends both, User-Agent and Accept on every Request.

Comment: I don't have access to the internals of the http client :( It's an Android Device.

Comment: BTW: "Accept: \*/\*" roughly means "send me any Content-Type you like". w3c says: If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types. If an Accept header field is present, and if the server cannot send a response which is acceptable according to the combined Accept field value, then the server SHOULD send a 406 (not acceptable) response.

Comment: By the way I added a new log capture of another client request. As you can see it does include the User-Agent as you said.  But I was ignoring requests with the Accept: */* so this caused big issues on my server.  The main issue I have is that I don't know how to tell when I should send the data and when I should ignore follow up client requests.

Comment: @heiko I modified the question a bit...  About the user agent, is that sent only one time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to serve audio or video it's likely that the client is trying to leverage [HTTP's Range header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35). The Range header allows features like skipping to the middle of an audio/video stream, scrubbing, etc. Desktop browsers often issue a couple of requests, one to discover if the Range header is supported, and a further request to actually begin streaming content. As long as your server can handle the client terminating socket connections you're probably safe to start streaming content for each connection.

If you're interested you could take a look at [Brisket](http://www.iamjohnstok.com/projects/brisket/) - it's a lightweight, Java-based HTTP server with Range header support.

Comment: Well, event if it sounds absurd, I can't rewind the data.  Once the request starts I go away with serving live content. I guess I'll have to manage to adapt to what you said about just serving no every request

Comment: Let me ask you this. Do you think that I should start serving on the first valid request and any subsequent request not serve the data?

Comment: What sort of data are you trying to serve? Is it files on a file system?

Comment: Well this server processes live data from a radio broadcast. It massages the data and serves it to the requesting clients.  Do you think that if I see a User-Agent field it is safe to assume I can start serving and any subsequent client proving request would not contain the User-Agent field so I would ignore such request.

Comment: I would probably use a push model. Keep track of all open requests. Read live data into a buffer. When the buffer is full write the data to each open request.

Comment: I don't believe a User-Agent header is mandatory - you should probably check the HTTP spec for protocol semantics 'on the wire'. Each request will have at minimum a request line and probably 1 or more headers: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5

Comment: Yeah, the current system I have is a bit complex... My temp solution is mutex around the serving area so that every new request must wait until the previous session is done... To avoid reading from the same live buffer feed.